# Match array string value inside id with index in Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array

```
public var options = [String]()
// VALUES = John-34 , Mike-56 , Marry-43 etc..
```

and I have function

```
 public func getIndex(id : Int){

        if let index = options.contains("-\(id)".lowercased()) {
            selectedIndex = index
            print("\(options[index])"). 
        }
    }
```

I want to get selected index with my function like ;

**getIndex(id : 34)**  // MUST BE SHOW John-34

but doesn't work ? Any idea? 
id is unique only must show 1 index.

Comment: Why do you make your life so hard with these weird compound parameters? This is an object oriented language. Use a custom struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`index(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1688966-index) for that.

```
public func getIndex(id : Int){
    if let index = options.index(where: { $0.components(separatedBy: "-").last == "\(id)" }) {
        print(index, options[index])
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Instead of hardcoding string like this make one `struct` or custom `class` that will helps you a lot.

```
struct Person { 
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}
```

Now make array of this struct and after that its easy to filter your array.

```
var options = [Person]()
public func getIndex(id : Int){
    if let index = options.index(where: { $0.id == id }) {
        print(index, options[index])
    }
}
```

Comment: dude, if id = 34 , and my array have 341,342,343 values ? I think will be come wrong one. Only must be come which unique id comping from getIndex(id : 341)

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper I have edited answer with `.components(separatedBy:)`  from contains check that

Comment: NOW only will be show TRUE unique id right ? with separatedBy

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper Why do you have an object index hardcoded in the object's name anyway?! It feels like you're the one creating the issue that you have to resolve now. ;)

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper Yes

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper Eric is right you need to make struct or custom class.

Comment: @NiravD ok but I need to get also index ?

Comment: @NiravD how can I get also index

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper Check the edited answer for that and use `index(where:)`

Comment: @NiravD ty man worked , I used for index ,  if let index = options.index(where: { $0.components(separatedBy: "-").last == "\(id)" }) {
            selectedIndex = index
        }

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper Welcome mate :) Also better if you use struct or class next time it will helps you a lot.